# MySQL Delete duplicates with different keys

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I messed up a couple of tables in my database with similar results but different keys.
The results are something like this:

```
1   |2   |3   
5   |25  |25
6   |25  |25
7   |31  |31
8   |31  |31
```

I would like to delete those duplicate rows so that the results are like this:

```
1   |2   |3
5   |25  |25
7   |31  |31
```

I tried `SELECT * DISTINCT 2 FROM TABLE` but that didn't work. Sorry I can't word it much better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
delete from your_table
where id not in (
                 select * from (select min(id) from your_table
                                group by col2, col3)
                 t_alias
                )
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06616/1)

Comment: does this not assume that column2 and 3 are always identical?

Comment: Note: "NOT IN (...)" will do nasty things if col2 happens to be NULL.

Comment: @jon: You are right. I added `col2` to the group

Comment: it didn't work, it just deleted the whole table except for one row (thank gods I was on a dummy table). thanks, anyway.

Comment: @user1524011: See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06616/1). It works there.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM the_table dt
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM the_table ex
    WHERE ex.col2 = dt.col2
    AND ex.col3 = dt.col3
    AND ex.id < dt.id
    );
```